# How patch android 4.4.2 wpa_supplicant for adhoc wifi

Tags: android, wifi, android-source

Now, I have a patch, but I don't know the version.

I use the patch in  android 4.4.2 source.

It can scan the adhoc WIFI but can't connect.

Please help how to do?

This is the [patch file](http://hi.baidu.com/kings0527/item/b7c329871b9b51c398255f04)

Comment: Do you mean that wpa_supplicant cannot connect to ad-hoc SSID from command line, or that your customized Android device still refused to connect to ad-hoc?

Comment: how to connect ad-hoc SSID from command line??????   The android source is skip the adhoc SSID when it scan. did it not ????

Comment: wpa_supplicant itself is a command-line tool. I guess that it can establish connection to an ad-hoc network. But the Android framework has some more logic involved, e.g. it makes sure that the network provides connection to internet.

Comment: yes, known. The patch file is delete the skip code and connect adhoc. Now, I can scan the adhoc but  can't connect.  So, I wanna known where  is the wrong code I didn't change.

Comment: It is not enough to change the supplicant to have your device connect to ad-hoc network. But before you begin to work on that part, you can work with you supplicant directly, and check if the supplicant can establish ad-hoc connection.